# How to generate unique combinations of cases to maximize a value while minimizing another?

Tags: r, function, statistics, combinations

I am currently trying to work on some code that I hope will be able to accomplish two things for data that looks like this (with about ~100 observations):

```
Lines <- "   key     error   money
1 7224 0.5500000 2483118
2 7223 0.5200000 2451469
3 7222 1.6600000 2425693
4 7247 0.6400000 2324070
5 7256 0.4400000 1785569
6 7248 0.2541168 1476720"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

I want to write  a function that will create various combinations of "key" (perhaps with the ability to threshold to n cases) in order to maximize "money" (at perhaps an arbitrary amount, say >=50,000 or <=30,000) while minimizing the "error" amount. A good way to think about it is that I want to create various portfolios of these keys on-the-fly.

I am still somewhat of an R beginner, so I understand that this may be a complicated function - I would mainly want a way to get started, but I am happy with a complete explanation as well. Thank you!

Comment: How are different keys combined? And how are the corresponding errors and moneys combined? Or by *"combinations of key"* do you mean *"values of key"*?

Comment: @Gregor What I had in mind was that the combinations would be various combinations of cases by `key` whose sums of `error` and `money` would be minimized and maximized to set thresholds.

@ZheyuanLi thank you for the tip! I've started looking at `combn` and it's absolutely the best place to start at. I suspect that I will have to use the `FUN = x` part of it do what I want.

Comment: With that clarification, it sounds like you have a [linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) optimization problem. If you search around SO or the internet there are several packages that will solve it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the problem is to find the subset of rows whose sum of errors is minimized subject to the sum of money being greater than or equal to some known constant M then it can be expressed as a *0-1 integer linear programming* problem:

> minimize error'x subject to money'x >= M and x is a vector of 0's and 1's

In terms of R code:

```
library(lpSolve)
M <- 4000000
res <- lp("min", DF$error, t(DF$money), ">=", M, all.bin = TRUE)

res
## Success: the objective function is 0.96 

DF$key[res$solution == 1]
## [1] 7223 7256
```

**N Best Feasible Solutions via num.bin.solns argument**

A proposed solution is said to be *feasible* if it satisfies the constraints. To get the N best feasible solutions, the following is supposed to work but it seems it's a bit buggy here. `?lp` does warn of this.  It would still be worthwhile to try it on your problem in case it does work on it.

```
N <- 3
res <- lp("min", DF$error, t(DF$money), ">=", M, all.bin = TRUE, 
          num.bin.solns = N, use.rw = TRUE)
```

**N Best Feasible Solutions via cutting planes**

Another possibility for N best feasible solutions is that for the ith solution cut off the first i-1 solutions by adding a constraint that excludes them and re-run:

```
res <- list(objval = 0)
N <- 3 # no of solutions desired

for(i in 1:N) {
  res <- lp("min", DF$error, rbind(DF$money, DF$error), ">=", c(M, res$objval * 1.0001), 
           all.bin = TRUE)
  print(res)
  print(DF$key[res$solution == 1])
}
```

giving:

```
Success: the objective function is 0.96 
[1] 7223 7256
Success: the objective function is 0.99 
[1] 7224 7256
Success: the objective function is 1.07 
[1] 7224 7223
```

One caveat is that this method will only return one of multiple values feasible solutions that give the same objective value (or objective values very near to each other).  For example, if there were two combinations that both had an objective value of 0.96 then the first iteration of the loop would find one of them and the second iteration would look for objective values >= 0.96 * 1.0001 hence it would eliminate both of them from further consideration.

**Note:**  The input `DF` in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "   key     error   money
1 7224 0.5500000 2483118
2 7223 0.5200000 2451469
3 7222 1.6600000 2425693
4 7247 0.6400000 2324070
5 7256 0.4400000 1785569
6 7248 0.2541168 1476720"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
```

Comment: This is basically it - and I appreciate the clarity that this illustrates. My intention was not to find subsets of rows, but to find various possible combinations of the rows so as to have options/choices of these `key` portfolios. Nevertheless, this is an amazing start, like @Gregor stated, as I did not know the proper terminology (linear programming).

Comment: See additional info added to post.